# AWS DynamoDB error "'blob' value should be a NSData type."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I can't solve this bug that I keep receiving for my program. What does this error means?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you post the stack trace and the piece of code where it's happening

Comment: he request failed. error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSJSONBuilderErrorDomain Code=4 "'blob' value should be a NSData type." UserInfo=0x7f8bc174ea50 {NSLocalizedDescription='blob' value should be a NSData type.}]

Comment: The*. It's a long piece of code.. not sure how I'm going to paste it here. But what does the error mean?

Comment: if you cannot post the code at a minimum you should specify the language and the sdk you are using. Guessing this is... interesting. I would say ios. And I would say that you are trying to pass in something that does not have the expected type: NSLocalizedDescription

Comment: Indeed, AWS sdk doesn't accept the type that I pass in. E.g. I pass in NSArray but the objects in the container are not AWSAttributeValue type, hence, this error appears.